# Matrix-Synapse Install Fails

Tags: matrix-synapse

I'm attempting to install a matrix-synapse home server on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

`sudo apt install matrix-synapse -y`  fails at *"Setting up matrix-synapse-py3 (1.11.1+bionic1) ..."*

With the message:  *Job for matrix-synapse.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.*

`journalctl -xe` returns:

*matrix-synapse.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certain **prerequisites** for installing matrix-synapse like python3, virtualenv, sqlite (if you are using sqlite database).

`sudo apt-get install build-essential python3-dev libffi-dev   python-pip python-setuptools sqlite3   libssl-dev python-virtualenv libjpeg-dev libxslt1-dev`

This command solves your issue.

If you want to install please follow [matrix synapse github](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/develop/INSTALL.md), or [upcloud document on synapse installation](https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/install-matrix-synapse/). These are quite helpful.